# Добавить файл или коммит в файл в определенную папку репозитория Github из VSC

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

У меня есть репозиторий на Github - mygit и там в нем папка лежит selectors-basics

Вот ссылка на него https://github.com/VitB2022/mygit/tree/master/selectors-basics

И там в папке лежат несколько файлов (html и css).

Мне нужно добавить в них коммит, а также например создать другие файлы в этой папке. При попытке пуша из VSC в эту папку репозитория у меня выскакивает ошибка error repository not found. Перед этим делал remote для https://github.com/VitB2022/mygit/tree/master/selectors-basics

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Прочитать «букварь» по гиту. Репозиторий у вас `…/VitB2022/mygit`

Comment: и? мне надо файлы поместить же именно в папку selectors-basics моего репозитория mygit (mygit/selectors-basics/)

Comment: Ну я и говорю — прочитать букварь.

Comment: Впрочем пока вообще непонятно что вы делали и что происходит. Напишите ваши конкретные действия и точные сообщения об ошибках

Comment: я создал у себя на ПК папку по адресу C:\MyGit\selectors-basics, открыл ее в VScode и уже в этой папке  создал файл index.html . Затем на гитхабе создал репозиторий mygit и в нем папку selectors-basics. Теперь мне в эту папку на гитхаб надо пушить коммиты из файла index.html . После команды git init, потом ремоута на папку https://github.com/VitB2022/mygit/tree/master/selectors-basics проходит без ошибок. Но как только даю комманду пуш, то идет ошибка error - repository not found